# Rayleigh Benard Convection analyzed as heat engine?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, heat-engine, non-equilibrium, convection

The treatment I've seen for Benard convection in a textbook is to derive approximate equations of motion and then show that there is a periodic solution matching the boundary conditions.  This is certainly interesting. But one drawback is that the solution seems almost too symmetrical.  If you tracked a parcel of fluid around its cyclic path and plotted it on a P-V diagram, it would enclose zero area.  That seems unphysical to me.  **Shouldn't each parcel of liquid be acting as a small heat engine, and do a net positive work to maintain the convective motion against viscous dissipation?**  After all, *something* must be doing work for the motion to remain steady.

It seems plausible that it would be approximately a  Carnot cycle, with the top and bottom branches of the path being isothermal and the vertical side branches being adiabatic.

I know atmospheric scientists have used a Carnot model or some modification to make predictions about atmospheric convection. But as far as I know they just assume the model and derive its consequences rather than attempt to analyze exactly how it is achieved.  Ideas?